# ImportError of mixins for Django 1.8 in Cygwin64

Tags: python, django, cygwin, importerror, mixins

I'm trying to setup a remote repository locally on my computer. 
The road has been bumpy, and now I'm stuck here with this error message:

```
from django.contrib.auth import mixins
ImportError: cannot import name mixins
```

The error does not appear until I runserver and write the url in a browser.

Based on answers of previous questions, I had installed the following (although they were not listed in the requirements of the project):

```
Django==1.11.18
django-filer==1.4.4
django-picklefield==2.0
django-polymorphic==2.0
```

And I think they solved the problem, but the project which I'm working on uses Django 1.8 , and when I install the versions of these that are compatible with Django 1.8, the mixins error comes back.

I'm using Cygwin (64-bit).

Edit: 
1) I had this project on another PC and it worked fine without having a version newer than Django 1.8.

2) If it helps, the error is from ".../rules/contrib/views.py"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, the error has resolved after a week of suffering.
Unfortunately, I don't know what exactly resolved it.
What I did was install all the following requirements:

```
bleach==2.1.4
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
Django==1.8.19
django-admin-tools==0.8.1
django-autocomplete-light==3.1.8
django-autoslug==1.7.1
django-autoslug-iplweb==1.9.4
django-bootstrap3==8.2.3
django-ckeditor==5.1.1
django-constance==1.2.1
django-cors-headers==1.1.0
django-email-extras==0.3.3
django-fobi==0.13.6
django-formtools==2.1
django-guardian==1.4.9
django-loginas==0.3.4
django-nine==0.1.13
django-nonefield==0.3
django-picklefield==1.0.0
django-post-office==2.0.8
django-tagging==0.4.6
django-tagging-autocomplete==0.5.0
django-userena==2.0.1
django-wkhtmltopdf==3.0.0
djangorestframework==3.1.3
easy-thumbnails==2.4.2
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
future==0.14.3
html2text==2014.12.29
html5lib==1.0.1
httplib2==0.10.3
idna==2.6
image==1.5.27
jdcal==1.3
jsonfield==2.0.2
oauth2==1.9.0.post1
oauthlib==2.0.4
olefile==0.44
openpyxl==2.5.4
Pillow==5.2.0
PyJWT==1.5.3
python-gnupg==0.4.1
python-openid==2.2.5
python-social-auth==0.2.21
python-twitter==3.1
qrcode==5.3
requests==2.19.1
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
rules==1.2.1
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.11.0
sphinx-me==0.3
unicodecsv==0.14.1
Unidecode==0.4.21
urllib3==1.22
vishap==0.1.5
webencodings==0.5.1
```

I don't know which one(s) did the job, so if anyone has an idea to what happened, please do tell so that others may benefit.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Auth mixins were introduced in Django 1.9. So If you really want only used those mixins You have to upgrade project to new Django.

If You want to use similar mixins they were actually ported to Django from project django-braces. django-braces 1.9 supports Django 1.8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, the error is still not resolved.